# Matching raster and feature class CRS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

So I am using a tool that analyses a raster and appends the analysis to a polygon feature class.

The tool fails to complete because the raster and the feature class has a different CRS.

Now I know I can change the CRS of the feature class using the `Project` tool but, since both the projected and geographic coordinate systems are different, do I need to match them both? If so how can I do this using the `Project` tool since the tool does not ask for a projected and geographic coordinate system? Should I run the tool twice to change the projected and geographic coordinate system one by one?

Basically I am trying to update the CRS of the feature class so that it matches that of the raster.

PS I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1

Raster CRS:

[image]

Feature class CRS:

[image]

Comment: You can't change the spatial reference of a file or enterprise geodatabase feature class. You *can* create a new feature class templated on the original, then append the old features that have been reprojected

Comment: You'll also want to have the ArcGIS Coordinate System Data setup installed to do the transformation (as part of the reprojection) from NAD83 NSRS2007 to NAD83 HARN.